# Copying to an empty folder?

Tags: c#

When i use the command :

```
FILE.copy(source path , destination path)
```

it's perform the copy just if in the destination path 
there is a file in the same name as the file i want to copy from the source path. 
actualy- it's replace it.
how can i perform copying that will create the file by itself?- i want to copy file to an empty folder!

Comment: You can create the directory using Directory.CreateDirectory and check if it exists using Directory.Exists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder must exist before copying files to it. So when you do:

```
File.Copy("d:\test\foo.txt", "d:\bar\foo.txt");
```

`d:\bar` must exist. If it does exist there are two possibilities:

1. It already contains `foo.txt` file inside -> in this case you will get an exception unless you use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx).
2. It doesn't contain a `foo.txt` file inside -> Now there are two subcases:

   2.1. The user you are running your program under has sufficient privileges to write to this folder -> in this case the operation succeeds

   2.2. The user you are running your program under doesn't have sufficient privileges to write to this folder -> you get an exception (actually you could also get some other exceptions if for example there isn't sufficient disk space, ...)

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have shown your code the problem is here:

```
File.Copy(
    Path.Combine(@dok.Letter,@"copy\Hackers.avi"),
    @"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop",
    true
);
```

You need to specify a filename in the destination:

```
File.Copy(
    Path.Combine(dok.Letter, @"copy\Hackers.avi"),
    Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop", "Hackers.avi"),
    true
);
```

Also for the sake of completeness you probably want:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
File.Copy(
    Path.Combine(dok.Letter, @"copy\Hackers.avi"),
    Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Hackers.avi"),
    true
);
```

Like this you don't need to hardcode the Desktop path.

Comment: @Shira, if `foo.txt` exists have you tried using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) and specify that you want to overwrite the file?

Comment: yes sure- in this case the copying succeeded- but if it doesn't exist - i get an error-  "the targrt is a directory not a file"

Comment: try
            {

                StartCopying = DateTime.Now;
                    File.Copy(Path.Combine(@dok.Letter,@"copy\Hackers.avi"),@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop",true);
                EndCopying = DateTime.Now;
                CopyingTime1 = (endCopying - startCopying);
                 a = CopyingTime1.Seconds;
  
                return ("copying finished successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;


            }

Comment: but i don't have the Hackers.avi in my desktop- i want the command to create it

Comment: @Shira, it will create it. The problem is that you are passing only `@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop"` as second argument to the File.Copy function whereas you should pass `@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop\Hackers.avi"`.

Comment: the desktop path helped me a lot  now it's more generic

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN `File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx):

> Copies an existing file to a new file

Are you sure this isn't working?  Perhaps paste in some code.

Comment: I'm sure   when i write  File.Copy(Path.Combine(@dok.Letter,@"copy\Hackers.avi"),@"C:\Users\sshap5x\Desktop\test\Hackers.avi",true);    if there is no file by the name Hackers.avi in test folder i get an error

Comment: "the target file "the path i have wrote" is a directory not a file"   it's took me time to run it.........

Comment: Try copying the target file path into explorer to make sure there are no spelling mistakes and in fact it does exist

Comment: i have no spelling mistakes, when i manualy copy this file to the target, the copying succeeded- it replaced it

Comment: look at the path- i'm writing the same path in 2 cases- at the first time in the test folder - Hackers.avi is exist and then the copying succeeded, at the secont time the test folder is empty- and then i got the error

Comment: Perhaps post a bit more of your code and add it to the question