# Copying a network file to a drive

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy a file from a nas to a drive, and I'm coming accross an error stating that the *"Target file `"c:\test"` is a directory, not a file"*. and I've looked at similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517733/copying-to-an-empty-folder) one in particular) but I still dont know where I'm going wrong! my code for the copy operation is;

```
File.Copy(CL, dest, false);
```

Where `CL` is equal to the "Current Location" in the loop (the location of the file as in `\\\\domain\music\file`) and `dest = @"c:\test"`.

Comment: please post more code where you declare CL, dest,  ect..

Comment: Try `c:test.txt` (or whatever the extension is for the file you're copying). `c:\test` is indeed a directory.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Huh? How do you recognize that it actually *is* a directory? It may be, or maybe not; AFAIK, files are not *required* to have an extension in Windows, are they?

Comment: @Piskvor: the "\" after the `c:` is what makes it a directory. `c:test` would indicate that it's an extension-less file named `test` in the `c:` directory.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Hmm, now I'm confused. I was always under the impression that `c:\ ` would mean the root directory of drive `c:`, `c:\test` would mean a file or directory in `c:\ `, and `c:\test\ ` would mean a directory in `c:\ `. I could be wrong though - it's been a while since I did Windows programming... *scurries off to check his assumptions*

Comment: @Piskvor: I could be wrong, too, but I think .NET agrees with me, at least. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a filename in the destination path.

You can do that by writing

```
Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(source))
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `copy` or `xcopy` on the command line, you have to specify the full name of the destination file in `File.Copy(source, dest, overwrite)`. To build the destination file name from the source file and destination directory, use

```
Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(sourceFile))
```

All together, using your variable names:

```
File.Copy(CL, Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(CL)), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also CL doesn't look like a file it appears to be a Directory